# How do I transfer my kindle collection to my new computer

Tags: kindle-cloud-reader

I have just bought a new computer all the books I have bought since using it are on my kindle and new computer My problemis I want the books that are on my old computer transferred to my new computer  I assumed I could use my cloud but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 2):

After adding your new PC to your Amazon account as a Kindle device, and after downloading Kindle software onto your new PC, then open the Kindle program, and choose Collections, click the plus sign, and choose Import Collections.

Comment: How to add new laptop to my Amazon account ?

Comment: I had that same question @Leo